# Android Oboe Library size

Tags: android, audio, opensl, oboe

We are trying to integrate Oboe and the library size seems to be big.We dont need any processing like resampling ,format conversion .This we do in app and would like to know if its possible to significantly reduce library size with our only requirement using Oboe being for Audio IO.

The source to configuring streams with flow graphs where lot of processing code seems to exist.Is there any easy way to take this processing code and use only Audio IO part.